# How to get xml department tag value in oracle?

Tags: xml, oracle

I want to get the deptno of the department tag. But I did not succeed. How can I do it?

```
<department deptno="10" dname="ACCOUNTING" location="NEW YORK">
    <employee empno="7782" ename="CLARK">
        <job>MANAGER</job>
        <mrg>7839</mrg>
        <hiredate>6/9/1981</hiredate>
         <sal>2450.00</sal>
    </employee>
    <employee empno="7839" ename="KING">
        <job>PRESIDENT</job>
        <mrg></mrg>
        <hiredate>11/17/1981</hiredate>
        <sal>5000.00</sal>
    </employee>
    <employee empno="7934" ename="MILLER">
        <job>CLERK</job>
        <mrg>7782</mrg>
        <hiredate>1/23/1982</hiredate>
        <sal>1300.00</sal>
    </employee>
</department>
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the output you want to have  as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables. ([edit] your question, do not post additional information in comments)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a simple XPath expression:

```
select extract(the_xml_column, '/department/@deptno')
from the_table;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9ba42ca7c37fd71060f0468cbe663077)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use **extractvalue**

```
select extractvalue(the_xml_column, '/department/@deptno') as deptno
from the_table;
```

document: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions054.htm